# My GCP storage bucket is only displaying images when I'm logged into Google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to GCP - have created a bucket that I want to use as a CDN to serve images and videos to my website. The problem I'm having is that when I'm logged in to Google my videos and images are displaying no problem, however when not logged They do not show.

I have added an allUsers member and assigned "storage object viewer" role - the bucket is tagged as public but still the content wont display

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated

Matt

Comment: Can you paste the URL of your image? (the path name can be obfucated, I mainly want to see the host name)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Making all objects in a bucket publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) and [Making individual objects publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects) and check if your images available through directly links. I've tried and in works for me from different devices. If you have no problems with direct access though provided at Cloud UI links you should check configuration CMS system of your site. I found this [example](https://geekflare.com/wordpress-media-google-cloud-storage/) for WordPress that could be useful.

Then, I've tried to disable public access for test purposes and got an error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to test-public-bucket-1/test-public-image-1.jpg.
</Details>
</Error>
```

Do you have any error messages when you're trying to reach your images and videos through directly links and via your website? If you have errors only while trying to view images and videos at website, you should check logs of web server that serve your website.

**EDIT** Have a look at the screenshots:

[image: bucket_example_1]

and

[image]

**publicly accessible link you can get by clicking on the link icon after word** `Public` as you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets):

> Once shared publicly, a link icon appears for each object in the
>   public access column. You can click on this icon to get the URL for
>   the object.

use it instead of `Link URL` that I noticed in your answer.

Meanwhile you use correct role `Storage Object Viewer` at the screenshot for `allUsers` and  this role has permission `storage.objects.get` as you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles). So, no research needed.

Did you mistype `Storage Object Viewer` role as `Storage Object Reader` in your answer?

Comment: Think I did this wrong earlier Serhii sorry.  I don't get error messages - when I try to access the links directly it takes me to a google login page...  I do have that wp-stateless plugin activated form the post you shared - my settings are exactly the same and I synced the content.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I did this wrong first time (new here).  The problem was with the WordPress CDN side as suggested in the solution offered above ...

I was trying to access the images and video’s without first uploading them through the WordPress media library - this meant the correct linking structure was not in place for WordPress to be able to resolve

Thank you for your time - and s as polities again for s as my confusion caused

Matt

Comment: @mattbylett please edit your initial question and don't post an answer in case you wish to add more information. Otherwise the thread is difficult to follow/understand